# Can we do Final Failover again if already a machine has been Failovered?

Tags: azure, migration, failover, server-migration, azure-site-recovery

I failovered a machine to Azure but can I later do its failover again using some other recovery point or because of some changes ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not completed migration you have an option to change the recovery point.